# how to apply view helpers to hash of arrays elements in rabl rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rabl

I have the following hash ,

```
baz = {"adults" : 2 ,"children" : 4 ,"foos" : [{"name" : "some_name","amount" : "123.00"}]}
```

I want do like

```
attributes :adults,:children
node :foos do |foo|
  veiw_helper(foo["amount"])
end
```

how can I apply helper methods to internal elements of array(here "foos") , thanks in advance.

Comment: I got the answer ,just I did like this after spending more time on rabl
     `node(:foos) do |baz|
      baz.foos.map do |foo|
       {:amount => view_helper(foo["amount"])}
      end
     end`